# How to create global helper function in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I create Global Helper functions in `react-native`?

I would like to use for accessing `sqlite` database or fetching data from server. Can I create a `JavaScript` file with functions and call that functions from multiple views?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38402025/1042409

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way we've done it in the past:

1. Create a file that exports a function:

   ```js
   module.exports = function(variable) {    
      console.log(variable);
   }
   ```
2. Require the file when you want to use it, in  a variable:

   ```js
   var func = require('./pathtofile');
   ```
3. Use function:

   ```js
   func('myvariable');
   ```

Comment: Could you please show how to do a callback to return some result?

Answer (score 5):

**global variable**

```js
class MainActivity extends Component {

  constructor(){
     super();

     // Creating Global Variable.
     global.SampleVar = 'This is Global Variable.';
  }
}
```

in second activity

```js
class SecondActivity extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
       <View>
          <Text> {global.SampleVar} </Text>
       </View>
   );
  }
}
```

But if you want to have a **global function**

```js
export function TestFunc1() {

}

export function TestFunc2() {

}
```

Then import and use

```js
import { TestFunc1 } from './path_to_file'
```

Answer (score 3):

2 methods, not sure which one is better:

1. Method

Use:

```
window.foo = function(val) {
   alert(val);
}
```

2. (Not really global) Inside your `class` where you export and require in the `need-to-use` file, you can define your function.

See this:

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  View,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

var MoviesScreen = React.createClass({
  foo : function(val) {
    alert(val);
  },

render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>      
      </View>
    );
  },
});


module.exports = MoviesScreen;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this helper function:

```
function myfunction(foo)
```

I declare it globally as:

```
global.myfunction = function myfunction(foo) {...};
```

Answer (score 1):

I did in a simple way like this:

1. I created a `helpers.js` file that will contain all the helper functions for my project & placed it like this: `./src/helpers.js`(you can place anywhere you like).
2. Exported the function like this from `helpers.js`:

   `export function GlobalLogout(str) {.....}`
3. Then I imported the function like this:

   `import { GlobalLogout } from '../src/helpers';`
4. And finally use the function in the file like this:

   `GlobalLogout(data);`

Hope this helps anyone!