# How to use global function with return in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a global helper file as most of the page will call to same function but with different parameters. I have try several ways and all did not return the value as if I place the script within the same screen.

I'm testing to get response from SOAP WSDL.

```
URL: 'http://mytesting.justdummy.com/android.asmx' 
Content-Type: text/xml 
SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/GetServerTime 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetServerTime xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have test it using Postman and I get the server time response.

Below is what I currently tried:-
Method 1:

```
const soapAPI= {
    fetchSOAPRequest: function (soapFunction, soapBody) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', global.valServerURL, true);
        // build SOAP request
        var soapRequest =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '<soap:Body>' +
            `<${soapFunction} xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` +
            soapBody +
            `</${soapFunction}>` +
            '</soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    return xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', `http://tempuri.org/${soapFunction}`);
        xmlhttp.send(soapRequest);
    }
}
export default soapAPI;
```

Method 2:

```
export const fetchSOAPRequest = async (soapFunction, soapBody) => {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', global.valServerURL, true);
    // build SOAP request
    var soapRequest =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
        '<soap:Body>' +
        `<${soapFunction} xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` +
        soapBody +
        `</${soapFunction}>` +
        '</soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    console.warn(soapRequest);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // Send the POST request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', `http://tempuri.org/${soapFunction}`);
    xmlhttp.send(soapRequest);
};
```

Method 3 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297804/3436326):

```
function fetchSOAPRequest(soapFunction, soapBody) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', global.valServerURL, true);
    // build SOAP request
    var soapRequest =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
        '<soap:Body>' +
        `<${soapFunction} xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` +
        soapBody +
        `</${soapFunction}>` +
        '</soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    console.warn(soapRequest);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                return xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // Send the POST request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', `http://tempuri.org/${soapFunction}`);
    xmlhttp.send(soapRequest);
}
function fetchAnotherAPI(date) {
    // your logic
 }
export {
    fetchSOAPRequest,
 };
```

**Method 1 and 2 is on the same '../components/services/soapAPI' file**

On main class where the return should happen.

```
import { fetchSOAPRequest, soapAPI} from '../components/services/soapAPI';
onTestingRetrieve = async () => {
    try {
        // call from export constant
        var myfirst = await fetchSOAPRequest('GetServerTime', '');
        // call from object and function
        var mysecond = await soapAPI.fetchSOAPRequest('GetServerTime', '');
        // call from function within same class file
        var mythird = await this.fetchSOAP('GetServerTime', '');
        // alert to show response for confirmation only
        Alert.alert('Response', JSON.stringify(resp));
    } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'SOAP request failed!\n' + e);
    }
}
//On render
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.onTestingRetrieve}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get server time</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But if I put the XMLHttpRequest within `onTestingRetrieve`, it will show the responseText without any problem as below.

```
onTestingRetrieve = async () => {
    try {
        const soapFunction = 'GetServerTime';
        const soapBody = '';
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', global.valServerURL, true);
        // build SOAP request
        var soapRequest =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '<soap:Body>' +
            `<${soapFunction} xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` +
            soapBody +
            `</${soapFunction}>` +
            '</soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>';
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    Alert.alert('Response', xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', `http://tempuri.org/${soapFunction}`);
        xmlhttp.send(soapRequest);

    } catch (e) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'SOAP request failed!\n' + e);
    }
}
```

I have search for tutorial, example and SO question but I still failed to get the server time. Can anyone go through the script and point on which part I'm missing?

Comment: Try using the fetch API https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

Comment: @Asleepace I have refer to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#using-other-networking-libraries and I cannot get how to have a return response from a global function as I have tried and received empty return.

Comment: From what I've seen (I dont usually use XMLHttpRequest), but they use Promises and resolve. Then you use await inside an async function. Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969495/in-javascript-how-do-i-should-i-use-async-await-with-xmlhttprequest I believe fetch implements Promise anyway, thus you don't need to use it if using fetch