# How to export functions and make them reusable in javascript / reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-reuse

I have a piece of code where I use it almost in all my components and is working perfectly fine but I would like to make it reusable.

I tried to export it in a different file then imported and pass the arguments on the function but it didn't work.

The searchTerm is simply an input where I set the state to the value of the input.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "User"
    email: "user@email.com"
    phone: 0000000
    gender: "male"
    notes: "some notes"
    birthday: "00/00/0000"
  }
]
```

What I have and want to reuse:

```
let filteredData = []

if (clients.length > 0) {
  filteredData =
    data.filter(d=> Object.values(d).join(' 
    ').toLowerCase().match(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
}
```

What I tried:

```
export function tableFilter(data, searchTerm) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    return data.filter(d => Object.values(d).join(' 
    ').toLowerCase().match(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
  }
}
```

The expected result's are to use the function in all my components without rewriting it. What I am getting now is no data at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: @EriksKlotins I mean I cannot filter the data and I cannot see the full list of the data.

Comment: please post sample input data and searchterm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402025/how-to-create-helper-file-full-of-functions-in-react-native may be helpful

Comment: You can remove the 0 check because filter will just return an empty array if the data is empty.

Comment: yes correct I remove it already

Answer (score 2):

The solution it was very simple :

```
export function tableFilter(data, searchTerm) {
  let filteredData = []
  // the if check is not necessary 
  if (data.length > 0) {
    filteredData = data.filter(d => Object.values(d).join(' 
    ').toLowerCase().match(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
  }
  return filteredData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the function in the root component and pass it to all the child components that use the functionality.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  tableFilter(data, searchTerm) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
         return data.filter(d => Object.values(d).join('')
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .match(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
       }
  }
  render() {
    return (<div>
             <Child1 myfilter={this.tableFilter} />
             <Child2 myfilter={this.tableFilter} />
             <Child3 myfilter={this.tableFilter} />
             <Child4 myfilter={this.tableFilter} />
             ...
           </div>);
  }
}
```