# how to use separate validation form in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-fullstack

I am new to ReactJS.

I want to separate the validation code from this file and move it to a new file that handles validation.

When I am trying to send the props from the render method, it is showing the validation three or four times. I know this is not the right way to do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { NotificationManager } from 'react-notifications';
import {AddService} from '../../api/service'
import { CSelect } from '@coreui/react';
import Validation from '../validation/service'

class AddEditForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        duration:'',
        price: '',
        validation : false,
    }

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitFormAdd = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault ()
        await this.Validation()
        if (this.state.validation == true) {
        //API
        }
    }

    submitFormEdit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault ()
        await this.Validation()
        if (this.state.validation == true) {
            //API
        }
    }

// VALIDATION FILE

    Validation = (e) => {

        let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(this.state.price);
        if (!this.state.name) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Enter Service Name', 'Info', 2000)
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.state.description) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Enter Description', 'Info', 2000)
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.state.price) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Phone price', 'Error', 2000)
            return false
        }
        if (!this.state.duration) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Service Duration', 'Error', 2000)
            return false
        }
        if (isnum !== true) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Enter Price in Number', 'Error', 2000)
            return false
        }
        else {
           this.setState({validation : true})
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.item) {
            const { id, name, description, price, duration } = this.props.item
            this.setState({ id, name, description, price, duration })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.item ? this.submitFormEdit : this.submitFormAdd}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="name">Name</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="name" id="name" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.name === null ? '' : this.state.name} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="description">Description</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="description" id="description" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.description === null ? '' : this.state.description} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="price">Price</Label>
                    <Input type="price" name="price" id="price" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.price === null ? '' : this.state.price} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="duration">Duration</Label>
                    <CSelect custom size="lg" name="selectLg" id="selectLg" value={this.state.duration} onChange={(e) => this.setState({duration : e.target.value})}>
                      <option value="">Select Duration</option>
                      <option value="3 Months">3 Months</option>
                      <option value="6 Months">6 Months</option>
                      <option value="1 year">1 year</option>
                      <option value="2 year">2 year</option>
                      <option value="4 year">4 year</option>
                    </CSelect>
                </FormGroup>
                <Button>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddEditForm
```

I want form validation in separate file and validate it through prop:

```
Validation = (e) => {

        let isnum = /^\d+$/.test(this.state.price);
        if (!this.state.name) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Enter Service Name', 'Info', 2000)
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.state.description) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Enter Description', 'Info', 2000)
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.state.price) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Phone price', 'Error', 2000)
            return false
        }
        if (!this.state.duration) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Service Duration', 'Error', 2000)
            return false
        }
        if (isnum !== true) {
            NotificationManager.error('Please Enter Price in Number', 'Error', 2000)
            return false
        }
        else {
           this.setState({validation : true})
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create the file and create a function in that file. This question has an answer that explains it

[How to create helper file full of functions in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402025/how-to-create-helper-file-full-of-functions-in-react-native)

you need to create the file validation.js

then

```
export function validation(e){
//your code

}
```

then import it in the file you currently have like this

```
import {validation} from './utils/validation'
```