# React Native create helper

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native, api

I am very new to react native and try to create my first app. I now want to create functions to get data from my api. How can I create a file with several functions (like in php) to get the data from my api.

For example:

- get_user()
- get_customer(customer_id)
- get_adress(user_id)
  and a lot more getter.

New helper function: (file=Data_funks.js):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import clientConfig from '../../client-config';


const helpers = {
    
    helper1: function(user_id){
        
         const get_bauleiter = async () => {
            try {   
                  const siteUrl = clientConfig.siteUrl + '/wp-json/zep/v1/' + user_id;
                  const response = await fetch(siteUrl, {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: {
                             Authorization: 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem( 'token' )
                        }
                  })

            if (response.status === 200) {  


                                let json = await response.json();
                                const array = json.data;
                                const error = array.error_code; 
                                const my_array=array.data_values[0][0];
                

                    if(error == 0){ 


                        var result =Object.entries( my_array );
//var result = Object.entries(my_array).map((key,values) => [key, my_array[key]]);
        
                        await localStorage.setItem( 'test', result);

                        return result;
                        
                        
                    }else{
                        
                        setData(1201);
                        
                    }

                }else {
                    
                        setData(1200);
                    
                }

                    } catch (err) { 
                        
                         console.log(err);  
                        
                    }
            }   
             
        get_bauleiter();     
             
        } //end helper1
    
} // end helpers


export default helpers;
```

Now I use to get the Array in this function here but it doesen´t work:

```
...
import React from 'react'
import {Alert, View, Text, Modal, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Linking} from 'react-native'

import Background from '../components/Background_2';
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton';
import funcs from '../components/Data_funks';

import Icon2 from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';



//##################### ICONS Importieren ##################### 
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from '@expo/vector-icons';


const Icon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(
  require('../../assets/icomoon/selection.json'),
  'IcoMoon',
  'zepra_icons.ttf'
);

//#############################################################




export default function ProjectsScreen({ route, navigation }) {

      const { data }    = route.params;
      const mail        = data.item.kontakte_mail;
      const test        = funcs.helper1(data.item.projekt_id);
      const testData    = localStorage.getItem( 'test' ); 
    
        var myArray = testData.split(',');
    
    
        var myArray = myArray.filter(n => n);

        console.log(myArray);
```

What I receive is this:

Array [
"contact_id",
"1",
"contact_unternehmen",
"47",
"contact_anrede",
"Frau",
"contact_titel",
"Dr.",
"contact_infos",
"Testinfo",
"contact_vorname",
"Olivia",
"contact_nachname",
"Candal",
"contact_position",
"Öffentlichkeitsarbeit",
"contact_strasse",
"Pariser Straße",
" 2",
"contact_zipcode",
"589885",
"contact_ort",
"Limburg an der Lahn",
"contact_land",
"Deutschland",
"contact_telefon",
"+49 (0)654545454454454545",
"contact_telefax",
"+49 (0)654545454454454545",
"contact_mobil",
"+49 (0)654545454454454545",
"contact_mail",
"olivia.candal@blabla.com",
"contact_buero",
"VDT e.V.",
]

---

Comment: Check this link it will be helpful:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960293/13632102)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. Creating the functions works but how do I return the object to the colling page?

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo, where I have returned different types of data: [Helper Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@appdelogico/helper-demo)

Comment: Your example is working if the function is setup like in your example. But how does it work in my exammple? It is not workin. I added the new function at the end of my question. How to use it in an async fetch function? I need your help please.

Comment: You need to use "await" while fetching data from storage.  like: `const testData = await localStorage.getItem( 'test' );
return testData;` Also you have to place this code after localStorage.setItem( 'test', 'cvcxv' );

Comment: Hi, Harsh, `const testData = await localStorage.getItem( 'test');` returns an error :Unexpected reserved word 'await' and if I pass `let json = await response.json(); const array = json.data; const testData = await localStorage.setItem( 'test', array ); return testData; `  returns null if I use `const testData =  localStorage.getItem( 'test');`

Comment: try adding 'async' before helper1 function. like. async  helper1: function(user_id)

Comment: Tryed it also but is not working. I updated my code above. Could you help me to fix the issue please? I am trying it since a week but it is not working :((

Comment: still not getting an array. How can I turn the respond to an array??

Comment: Check previous demo, and make changes accordingly: 
https://snack.expo.dev/@appdelogico/helper-demo

Comment: I tryed your example. Copyed all scripts in my project without any changes, Still receiving the following error: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_Data_funks.helpers.get_bauleiter'); Data_funks.js is the file where my helper is defined.

Comment: I made changes in previous demo. check helper.js. I removed const declaration of helper. and wrote functions directly. also in App.js I'm retrieving that data in useEffect.