# In react native how to reuse functions?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**I need access functions from another page in react native .**

Example :

```
validateEmail = (email) => {
// ---- Code ----
}
```

I need access that function in both login.js and registration.js

Comment: You can see the answer by @Nader Dabit here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539774/how-to-create-global-helper-function-in-react-native)

Comment: That's Work @zakster But
1.  Create a file that exports a function:
    module.exports = function(variable) {    
    console.log(variable);
    }
Here we can only declare single function , How to declare multiple functions ?

Comment: Here is a short and nice answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38402100/2833640

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can give you a quick example which I use in my current project.

You can follow the steps:

1.Create a /utils folder which you can put all the shared functions files for example datetimeHelper.js

```
const dateTimeHelper = {
  getFormattedDatetime: (datetime) => {
    return moment.utc(datetime).local().format('MMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a');
  }
}

export default datetimeHelper;
```

2.Import the file into where you need it:

```
import datetimeHelper from './utils/datetimeHelper.js';
```

3 You can call the functions:

```
datetimeHelper.getFormattedDatetime(MY_DATETIME);
```

Comment: i use this code but showing undefined is not an object (evaluating _ApiHelper.ApiHelper.getdata)

Comment: Hi @AslamPatel, Can you share the code so I can help you find out?

Comment: Thanks, similar approach `utils` directory having a variety of `helpers` such as validation, working with dates, and so on. Good approach!

Comment: Shouldn't this read `import dateTimeHelper` and not `import DateTimeHelper` or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file at application root named as `Common.js` and inside common.js file add this:

```
'use strict';

class Common {

    //here you can use your validation email code

}

module.exports = Common;
```

Now access this class wherever you want.

Comment: How to access the functions inside the Common.js @Ankush Rishi

Answer (score 0):

For the first question as I wrote in the comments you can use this:

[Export one function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539774/how-to-create-global-helper-function-in-react-native)

If you want to export many functions you can use this:

[Export many functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402025/how-to-create-helper-file-full-of-functions-in-react-native)

You can use the same technique for other things also like styles, fonts, colors and so on.

These questions are duplicates and for this reason I add the links here.

Answer (score 0):

I have created reuseable function as below:

Helper.js
import { Platform, Dimensions } from "react-native";

```
function isIphoneWithNotch() {
    const dimen = Dimensions.get("window");
    return (
        Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
        !Platform.isPad &&
        !Platform.isTVOS &&
        (
            dimen.height === 780 ||
            dimen.width === 780 ||
            dimen.height === 812 ||
            dimen.width === 812 ||
            dimen.height === 844 ||
            dimen.width === 844 ||
            dimen.height === 896 ||
            dimen.width === 896 ||
            dimen.height === 926 ||
            dimen.width === 926)
    );
}

export { isIphoneWithNotch };
```

Use this function:

```
import { isIphoneWithNotch } from "./Helper";

console.log(isIphoneWithNotch());
```