# How to access the function of another component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm facing a problem in the app I was trying to create. I have three components. So, in the main component, I fetch the data and send the data to the progressbar component, when the progressbar loads, I want to access the function of another component. how do I access the function of the other component?

Main Component

```
{analysis.tontop.map(({ tone, value }) => (
                    <MyProgressBar
                      onClick={() => this.handleSentClick(tone)} //this is where I want to call the function of the sound component. or is this not the correct place to call the function of the other component?
                      value={value}
                      text={tone}
                      key={tone}
                    />
                  ))}
```

Progressbar component

```
const MyProgressBar = ({ value, text, onClick }) => {
  return (
      <ProgressBar
        onClick={onClick}
        max={100}
        now={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The component from where I want to access the function from

```
function Sound(tone, enteredText) { 

  const handleSentClick = ({ tone, onClick }) => { 
    //this is the function that I want to access in the main component
      console.log('something something');
    };
```

Comment: using export and import, or am i mistaken?

Comment: Are you actually using `Sound` component in `MainComponent`? And can you show a little more code instead so we know how Sound, Progressbar and MainComponent are actually used with eachother?

Comment: @ErtanHasani yeah the sound component is inside mainComponent but the progressbar is in another file which I imported. it's actually a very big app, so I just posted the  parts that I thought would be necessary for this question

Comment: i think the function handleSentClick() should be reside in main component class, as you are calling using this operator

Comment: there are some data fetching to be done in the sound component so I placed the handleSentClick function there which will do some action after the data fetching is done. I just added console log here just for some demonstration.

Comment: It's very difficult to picture what you're trying to do without seeing it on a page. In general, components should represent some DOM. If you're trying to use the "play a sound" bit, of a sound component (which may be a button that you don't want on this page), you need to extract that part of the functionality OUT of the sound component and export it in a separate file that both SoundComponent and ProgressBar can make use of.

Comment: try to import using destructure. import {handleSentClick } from "./Sound" in MainComponent. This will allow to to directly use this function

Comment: @EdHinchliffe my program is such that, when you click the submit button on main component, a progressbar will appear, then when you click on the progressbar, then a function of the sound component should be evoked that plays a sound from the sound component which we receive from an api. I just want to know how to link all those components together or is there any other approach for this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use another components inner function directly since there is no parent - child relation, my suggestion is to use some state management library for that kind of functionality, like [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react) or  [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/)
which lets you can dispatch functions and retrieve some data from application state via component props. You may check out [this](https://medium.com/@paulfitzgerald_11524/quick-and-easy-guide-to-implementing-redux-in-a-react-app-5072e3a81b7a) article for how to implement redux on existing react project.

Comment: redux seems way too complicated for my simple app. i just need to play a sound which I will receive from an api in the sound component when I click on a progressbar, that progressbar I will receive when I click the submit button on the main app. as you can see that I have integrated the <MyProgressBar> in the mainComponent, can't I do something similar for the Sound component

Comment: You may seperate the function which you want to call globally then. Create a global functions.js and export sound function from there, then import to any component which do you want to call that function. But i suggest you to use a state management library still, you may choose mobx which is easier to use than redux. Check out for how to create helper functions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539774/how-to-create-global-helper-function-in-react-native